# Update table Where IN shows Error Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have the stored proc as follows, it always shows the following error whenever I execute it:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here's the stored proc code:

```
DECLARE @Wishlist_AutoID VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT Wishlist_AutoID FROM ecommerce.ShoppingCartItem WHERE AutoID = @CartItem_AutoID)
DECLARE @Fulfiller_AutoID BIGINT = (SELECT a.Member_AutoID FROM ecommerce.ShoppingCart a INNER JOIN ecommerce.ShoppingCartItem bON a.AutoID = b.ShoppingCart_AutoID)

UPDATE ecommerce.WishList
SET isFulfilled = 1, FulfilledOn = GETDATE(), FulfilledBy = @Fulfiller_AutoID
WHERE AutoID IN (
  SELECT data FROM dbo.Split(@Wishlist_AutoID, ';')
)
SET @Result = @@ROWCOUNT
RETURN @Result
```

Comment: I thought the question was quite clear and understandable. Nothing else to add, by the way, it has been resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of you first two variable assignments is the problem:

```
DECLARE @Wishlist_AutoID VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT Wishlist_AutoID FROM ecommerce.ShoppingCartItem
                                         WHERE AutoID = @CartItem_AutoID)
```

OR

```
DECLARE @Fulfiller_AutoID BIGINT = (SELECT a.Member_AutoID FROM ecommerce.ShoppingCart a 
                                    INNER JOIN ecommerce.ShoppingCartItem b
                                     ON a.AutoID = b.ShoppingCart_AutoID)
```

These queries could return more than one row, and you can't assign multiple rows to a scaler variable.

Given their subsequent usage, I would say it is the second assignment (`@Fulfiller_AutoID` ).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That query isn't complete... anyway I couldn't work on it right now, I'll solve it tomorrow and will mark as answer if all goes well!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, in either of the lines;

```
DECLARE @Wishlist_AutoID VARCHAR(MAX) = (
  SELECT Wishlist_AutoID
  FROM ecommerce.ShoppingCartItem 
  WHERE AutoID = @CartItem_AutoID)

DECLARE @Fulfiller_AutoID BIGINT = (
  SELECT a.Member_AutoID FROM ecommerce.ShoppingCart a 
  INNER JOIN ecommerce.ShoppingCartItem b
    ON a.AutoID = b.ShoppingCart_AutoID)
```

...your query returns more than one row, so the assignment to a *single* `VARCHAR`/`BIGINT` variable is invalid.